# Trying to open connection for oracle server using powershell

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to open connection to oracle server and getting below error

Code :

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=$result;User ID=$userID;Password=$orapwd"
$OracleConnection =New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$OracleConnection.Open()
write-host $OracleConnection.state()
```

Error :

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:18 char:20
+ ... Connection =New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($con ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:22 char:1
+ $OracleConnection.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:23 char:1
+ write-host $OracleConnection.state()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:24 char:1
+ $OracleConnection.Close()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with the oracle database. The error say that there is no type `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection`, did you make sure you imported everything that is necessary?

Comment: Try adding `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient` at the top of your script

Answer (score 0):

$con.Open()  ;

```
 $con.State | Write-Host;
```

AFAICT, State is a property, not a function....  Should return either Open or Closed (if the connection object is valid).